# Navier-Stokes equations through a orifice

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I have reactor that looks as follows :

[image: initial]

In the first part, my reactants flow in.  The reaction is started and generates heat as a result.

It then expands slightly into the second part where after it is forced through a smaller opening, compressing the gases. The compressed gas then once again expands.

The reactor kinetics are not that important for now, I can do that.
However, I do not know how to use NS-equations where the fluid expands, compresses and then expands.

I only ask that someone throws me in the right direction so that I may further research this.

Comment: Are you wanting to know how to use/solve the NS equations *numerically* or *analytically* in the region?

Comment: What level of answer are you looking for? An analytical solution? RANS, LES, DNS? This is a problem that could take months on a massive super computer to solve correctly depending on what kind of analysis you are trying to do.

Comment: Chapter III Turbulance models may help you, but as fellow commenters have suggested, it is a tough problem to crack. See http://waset.org/publications/4244/investigation-on-fluid-flow-characteristics-of-the-orifice-in-nuclear-power-plant

Comment: Given your last sentence and the fairly broad nature of the question (i.e., whole books are written on the subject), I've added in a resource-recommendation tag to prevent closure (and seems to be in-line with what you want).

Comment: I see now that it is a bit vague.  I have a gas, entering at approximately 1300C.  A reaction then takes place, which causes a temperature increase down the reactor.  The pressure drop in the horizontal direction can be determined by the Ergun equation as far as I know.

Comment: I would however like to know how the bottleneck affects the density and velocity of the gas.  The pressure can be recalculated for each part if necessary.  I hope this answers most of the questions you have.

Comment: I would also like to add that I have Matlab to my disposable.  This reactor will form only 1 chapter in my 8 chapter final year project due sometime in October.  I have time now to start developing the model for it.  If any of you have a reason why I should not do it, I will listen.  However, not taking into account how the fluid moves through the bottleneck, may impact the accuracy quite a bit.

Comment: I'll try to answer this when I get out of class.

Comment: I have an idea to simply it quite a bit.  How about just viewing the system in 2D.  Then rotate the graph about the central axis? I think it will give a good representation of the flow and keep the calculations simpler?